# git - deleted remote branch head causes pull error

Tags: git

I have a git repo that had a branch named development. The development branch was deleted (on purpose), and a new branch for a feature added. The feature is now complete and I need to merge the feature branch into master. When I try to pull master I get

```
 Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/development
 unexpected end of command stream
```

How do I get past this error?

**Edit**
Output of git branch -vv

```
 create-config d9fb7e3 correct formatting error in post view
 * master        2ff7dd7 fix merge
```

Comment: post the output of the `git branch -vv` command. Perhaps your *master* is set to pull from the remote *development* branch.

Comment: Are you sure you are on branch `master` before pulling? (git branch -a) for checking

Comment: @w0lf posted. Thanks.

Comment: @Nguyen I am on master. thank you

Comment: Apparently your *master* is not tracking any remote branch. Being on the *master* branch, try properly setting the tracking branch: `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master`. And then see the `git branch -vv` output and try pulling again.

Comment: @w0lf the command returns that origin/master doesn't exist...I am becoming more confused :)

Comment: What is the output of `git branch -a`?

Comment: @w0lf it is the same as `branch -vv` above, without the details. It shows that I have 2 branches, and I am on `master`

Comment: Weird. Could it be that you do not have a remote? (`git remote`)

Comment: @w0lf I don't think so. I started with a clone.

Comment: try cloning the repo to a different directory and see the output of `git branch -vv` there

Comment: @w0lf created new directory, cloned the repo, `git branch -vv` returns nothing...

Comment: @w0lf I manually edited the local repository .git/config file. That fixed the problem... I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the local git configuration manually. It is located at .git/config in the directory in which you are working.

I found that the main branch was tracking the now deleted development branch on the remote. I changed the branch name from development to master on the lines that referenced the incorrect remote branch.

incorrect:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://XXXXXXXX.com/folder
fetch = +refs/heads/development:refs/remotes/origin/development
```

corrected:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://XXXXXXXX.com/folder
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I hope this helps someone. Thanks to @w0lf for helping me.